# Notepad++ new-line

Tags: notepad++

I want to change the following lines :

```
note: 10    name: A
note: 08    name:  B
note: 12    name:  C
note: 16    name:  D
```

to this

```
name: A
note: 10
name: B
note: 08
name: C
note: 12
name: D
note: 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `^(note:\s*\d+)\s+(name:.*)`
Replace with: `$2\n$1`

**Do not** check `Dot matches newline`.